# Request to blacklist the [covid-19] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

While [covid-19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) may be a topic on many of our minds right now, it doesn't really relate to coding. At best, it's a meta-tag. At worst, it's just offtopic on Stack Overflow.

Can we please burninate and blacklist it?

Comment: I've removed the tag from the questions.  Hopefully another is not posted and the tag will be deleted tonight.

Comment: I've also cast close / delete votes where necessary. That should help.

Comment: 0 questions in the tag so it's gone

Comment: There was also [tag:coronavirus] on one question which I removed.

Comment: Ignorance-prompted: Is there a mechanism to prevent arbitrary re-creation of said tag?

Comment: @Adrian that's what blacklisting is.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ignorance, again! You wanna give me link to blacklisting?

Comment: The closest I have is the [\[blacklist-request\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blacklist-request) tag wiki. See also [\[tag-blacklist\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks! I found a discussion already. Like I implied, I'm not very *au fait* with tag burns stuff.

Comment: I just had to remove the coronavirus tag from a graphing question. Can this be considered a request for both of these as well as “corona”, which they used first?

Comment: @BSMP [tag:Corona] has a wiki, it seems to be about a specific framework which from my point of view looks to house mostly on topic questions; although I expect it to get abused many times in the coming weeks. I think blacklisting the ones that are obviously about the virus and just keeping an eye on "Corona" for off topic questions should be good enough.

Comment: @DavyM _coming weeks_ seems a bit hopeful. They had already started in January  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hdMN.png

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394795/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-data-tag) blacklist request for [tag:covid-19-data]

Comment: Can the blacklist get applied? Just untagging and closing is apparently not enough, as an.... active user ... [just seems to have re-tagged them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) (or maybe not same ones, but there's 4 again)

Comment: @DanMašek ["Only the dev team is able to add tags to a site's blacklist,"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/blacklist-request/info) so we have to wait on an employee to do it. Might be 6-8 hours, days or weeks.

Comment: On the other hand, if we leave it while questions are pouring in, we can systematically close those questions as needed, and retag the rest instead of leaving them scattered across various tags.