# Request to blacklist the [covid-19-data] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, blocklist-request

Very related to "[Request to blacklist the [covid-19] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394683/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-tag)".

A user [created](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60799853/revisions) the [covid-19-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covid-19-data) tag, yesterday.

I feel like the tag doesn't add any relevant information to the question, lust like [student-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/student-data) has no added value on a database management question. As with [covid-19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/covid-19), at best, it's a meta-tag, and at worst, it's off-topic, but as it's already been added to 25 questions, I didn't want to unilaterally undo the decision of one user.

That said, the tag could (as far as I could see) be removed with as edit message:

> *"The subject matter of the data is completely irrelevant to the question."*

<sub>(I've also tagged this [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request), as this feels like a little more than just editing one misguided question.)</sub>

Comment: The user who has been adding that tag also had added information to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/covid-19-data/info). Seems like they genuinely believe this tag should exist for some reason. For that person and anyone else wondering why this kind of tag isn't appropriate, here's Jeff's article about [the death of meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: I've already [prodded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819400/what-do-i-need-to-be-able-to-use-this-covid-19-data#comment107606296_60819400) the user with a link to this discussion. I hope he sees this.

Comment: Just noticed that the user also edited the [Covid-19](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/covid-19/info) wiki inviting users to make other Covid-19-* tags...

Comment: @DavyM: I've edited that tag wiki to make it clear the tag is not to be used.

Answer (score 28):

I agree that this is a meta tag; data is data no matter what it's about. Tags about data for a specific event in real life do not need to exist, so I agree with burnination and blacklisting.

Do note that this tag qualifies for abbreviated burnination/cleanup since it has fewer than 50 questions. If you can get the sign-on of another trusted user (20k+) then there should be no issue with us going through and removing the tag. Of course, that won't stop a misguided user from trying to re-add it. For that we *do* need blacklisting.

Comment: Considering there's plenty of support for the removal of the tag, and not a single vote or comment indicating it should stay, I'm editing it out and close/delete-voting where necessary.

Comment: You have my support on this particular issue, if you ever find yourself in need of it in the future. :-)