# Tag synonym reversal request: corona <-> coronasdk

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

With the current virus outbreak, a [unfortunately named SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/corona/info)'s tag is getting questions about (data regarding) the virus itself.

I think it may be a good idea to reverse the coronasdk -> corona synonym, so that [coronasdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coronasdk) is the "primary" tag for that SDK, or maybe even to *completely remove the synonym*, so we can more easily clean up questions that have the "[corona]" tag added as meta tag.

(See also "[Request to blacklist the [covid-19-data] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394795/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-data-tag)" for related discussion about removal of those meta tags.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done, results may still be cached for a while.

1. Swap synonyms, then merge to move all the questions into [coronasdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coronasdk)

```
updating post history, 3942 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 3127 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'coronasdk' doesn't exist, renaming to 'corona'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [coronasdk] and [corona] complete!
remapping 1 synonyms
771 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
588 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

2. Synonym deleted:

[image]

Now we get an empty [corona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corona) tag.

Comment: Samuel, I see the synonym is still there. I think it may be a good idea to _remove_ the synonym, as that will make questions tagged with [corona] stand out more.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the second part of the sentence.