# Request to reinstate and use the [c3ai-datalake] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

#### Discussion

Based on discussions on the [[covid-19]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394683/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-tag) and [[covid-19-data]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394795/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-data-tag), a user has untagged all questions using the [c3ai-datalake] tag because it related to COVID-19.

However, the [c3ai-datalake] tag is *not* a meta tag -- questions that had been posted under the tag related to the specific use of the [C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake](https://c3.ai/covid). There's precedent for tags related to specific APIs, like [[facebook-graph-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api) and [[youtube-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api). Based on the discussion in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126579/error-when-running-evalmetrics-api-on-outbreaklocation), I don't see any good argument for this being a meta-tag. It's a useful tag that (1) can be used as the only tag on a question, and (2) is not subjective, and is thus not a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). It's valuable for questions having to do with the specifics of the API documented [here](https://c3.ai/covid-19-api-documentation/), like the "includes" and "filter" fields, which are specific to the API.

Could we keep this tag given its value in identifying questions related to the COVID-19 Data Lake? If something like [c3-api] would be clearer, that seems like a reasonable option too.

#### Proposed tag wiki

The [C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake](https://c3.ai/covid/) provides a free and public RESTful API to access a variety of COVID-19 datasets in one unified data image.

Use this tag to ask and answer questions related to accessing and using the C3.ai COVID-19 Data Lake API. In particular, use this tag for questions related to:

- the specifics of API calls like `fetch`, `evalmetrics`, and `getarticlemetadata`
- joining data across multiple data types using `include`
- implementations of concepts specific to the Data Lake in Python, R, or other tools that access the API

Comment: _"If there are issues with the API itself, SO isn't the place for those questions, as they need to be asked to their support team, any way."_

The other tags you mention have specific documentation, and experts on that subject. That C3.ai API seems to lack documentation.

That aside, you'd need a separate language tag, as the API is just an endpoint. The way you communicate with the API depends on the language you're using.

Comment: Now, if you want that tag added any way, I'd suggest adding a (draft) tag wiki to this meta question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I added a draft tag wiki.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag. Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question. ([source](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/))

You need a programming language added to the question, as the API is just an endpoint. How you communicate with it depends on the language.

---

My personal major gripe with that *product*, is that there is ***no publicly accessible documentation*** available for it, so the only people that could really answer questions about that *product*, are those that develop it.

We're not <company>'s tech support.

Yes, I realize they're not making money off of the API, but you are trading your PII for access.

Comment: I understand the concern on the API docs being behind a sign-up form. That is annoying, but I don't see it as a reason to exclude this topic from Stack Overflow. Regarding using a programming language, I don't think that the intention of removing meta tags is to remove all tags that could possibly be used in combination, but to remove tags that can *only* be used in combination. This one is in the first category -- it can be used for questions specific to the API, without a language, as well as questions that relate to a specific language.

Comment: So far, most of the questions I've seen it tagged on were more about how to `fetch`. The API wasn't very relevant.

Comment: you keep bringing up different points but none of these meet the criteria described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination). Specifically, the tag is not causing harm and does not fail  the tests described there.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't understand why missing or inaccessible documentation has to do with not approving an associated tag. There are questions on frameworks/apis with out of dated or missing or not very well quality documentation.

Comment: @Cerbrus in the grand scheme of things, I think we can both agree that this tag is not that important. But it provides a lot of value for people trying to use this service -- it's the fastest and easiest way to get Q&A on this specific coding topic, and that's why people come to Stack Overflow in the first place. I and the others that have used the tag would really appreciate it if you would reinstate it and add it back to the questions it was removed from.

Comment: Regardless of the outcome of this question, I can assure you ___I___ am certainly not adding the tag myself. “It provides value for people” is not a valid criteria to add a SO tag.

Comment: @bachr: I see you've decided to __take matters into your own hands__ and re-added the tags. Don't do that when a meta discussion is ongoing. I've reverted the edits.

Comment: @Cerbrus that's because I see that the discussion is heading into a wall, there is no need for so much philosophy, we just need a tag that refers to a specific technology.

Comment: @bachr: But that's not up to you alone to decide.

Comment: @Cerbrus OK then how are we gonna reach agreement on this. We definitely need a separate tag!

Comment: This question. Give it some time.