# Should we identify COVID-19 related programming questions? If so, how?

Tags: discussion

COVID-19 has caused at least 250K deaths [and counting](https://news.google.com/covid19/map?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen).  Firms such as auto makers, fashion houses, and distilleries have changed their product lines to address the pandemic.

While programmers working on COVID-19 research probably have similar Q's to other programmers, is there a way we can identify these questions for people who want to contribute specifically to the response by answering?

Let's stipulate that [meta-tagging](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) is out of the question (see blacklist requests [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394683/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-tag) and [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394795/request-to-blacklist-the-covid-19-data-tag)).

Are there other, appropriate responses?  Ideas might include

- Meta SO list of COVID-19 related questions
- A chat room
- Something controlled by the moderators, similar to the featured tag.

**These ideas are not great, hence my question.**

I can see a couple possible perspectives here:

1. We should not add noise to the site by [promoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) [specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114203/why-has-the-sopa-banner-disappeared-from-the-site-header/114240#114240) [causes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow) or by referencing subject domains.  It shouldn't matter whether the OP is fighting a pandemic or hacking into a database of cat videos for homework.
2. Covid-19 is a unique threat.   We can find an unobtrusive way to help people who want to use their programming talents to do something about it specifically, beyond the worthy goal of contributing to general programming knowledge.

Comment: First of all, the logo change surrounding the legalization of same-sex marriage. It was a one-time thing, and nothing similar has been done since. Moreover, the company isn't what it used to be. the 100k swag is now dead for an instance. And what're you gonna do? Rename the site CovidOverflow until there's a vaccine? There's already more than enough info being spread around this, and opening for covid-related questions starts one major problem: filtering out wrong information. The problem here is that this is a programming-oriented site, not a site where you ask medical professionals.

Comment: Covid-related questions still have to be on-topic for the site. Some research indicates Covid might go on for 2 years before it stops. If we allow covid-related questions for that entire time, all we get is a pile of off-topic trash to clean up later. Also, the summer of love thing was a one-time event that changed the logo. That is vastly different from changing a question policy, because the devs can clean it up with a change to the favicon.

Comment: @Zoe thanks I clarified to "COVID-19 related programming questions".  An example could be a researcher trying to fix a bug using some bioinformatics or epidemiology library.

Comment: I still don't see the point in separating out a group of questions, just because they're about a current event. Questions are still meant to be equally worth, and if stuff gets highlighted just for being related to covid, there's an entire field of abuse that shows up.

Comment: Why would that be different if the data is Covid-19 data or any other data that the computational biology library could process?

Comment: ... or people who claim to contribute to the response purely for rep. Everything can and will be abused if there's a reward for it. if you don't believe me, there's scammers in the real world taking advantage of covid for money, or just for their own satisfaction of scaring people.

Comment: It's just as off topic as any other "meta tag" would be :/....

Comment: Hi folks - I don't think we should be closing or deleting questions like this.  If nothing else, we can use them as a signpost or a dupe target when the question inevitably comes back up again.

Answer (score 21):

Are Covid-19 questions programming questions?  If so, then they're questions about programming which happen to *also* concern the specific domain of medical science, and don't have to have any facts or pretense about the domain of medical science at all.

In other words, **we don't care what the med tech domain actually is**, so long as the technical question can be answered like any other technical question.  Labeling them as anything to do with any disease, ailment or pandemic would be noise at *best* since no programmer should know how to solve those problems to be able to answer questions about someone's Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess my question is: *should* we care what the domain is?  Your answer is fine.  Someone might have a different perspective -- "I have time to answer one question today... which one would help someone working on a cure?"  Or "maybe I'll answer a couple more questions since it would help out with the crisis."

Comment: The direct response to "should we care what the domain is" has remained a steady **no** on this site for quite some time.  This applies not just to medical science, but also to people asking questions which have some level of gray morality (e.g. hacking).  If one has a question to ask about programming, that's fine.  It does not matter - at the end of the day - if their question pertains to something specific with a pandemic or hacking or whatever, so long as it's on-topic here.  *Just* talking about Covid-19 is thoroughly off-topic here.

Comment: *"we don't care what the med tech domain actually is"* - you don't want to answer that on a interview question "What could you do about covid-19?". Nor you can tell for all. Of course we care. It just have to be on-topic question, then you or me surely can help. Currently if its asked it will drove in bunch of other questions, while it could potentially get your or mine priority somehow. A tab "today's covid-19 questions" could do. The problem is to prevent me or others unrelated to be able to post there our questions.

Comment: @Sinatr:  If I got that question as part of an interview I think I'd walk out.  I'm not being interviewed based on my ability to solve Covid-19.  I'm being interviewed on my technical abilities which can enable solutions to Covid-19.

Comment: @Makoto, I mean TV interview (or similar) where you was invited as a famous java programmer and just answering a bunch of questions.

Comment: @Sinatr:  I *really* don't think you're getting it.  I'm just another dev in a sea of them and I doubt I'll rise to any level of fame anytime soon.  But even if I did and even if I were asked that question, I still think I'd walk out since the premise of the question is *ridiculous*.  "You're smart and good with computers; can you fix Covid-19 for us?"